# Make all EF Core model properties virtual for mocking in unit tests with Moq and xUnit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I am using the [repository pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/choosing-a-testing-strategy#repository-pattern) as suggested by the documentation for unit testing in EF Core. I have reached a point in my code where I am not able to fully test a method properly as a result of doing operations on the models from EF Core and not the DB Context.

An example of what I mean is below:

**Code to be tested**:

```
    private static void AddToUserScore(Members member)
    {
        var basePoints = 2;

        if (member.HintAsked)
        {
            basePoints--;
            member.HintAsked = false;
        }

        if (member.LocationHintAsked)
        {
            basePoints--;
            member.LocationHintAsked = false;
        }

        member.UserScore += basePoints;
    }
```

**EF Core Context Model itself:**

```
public class Members
{
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public int AppId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int UserScore { get; set; }
    public string QuestionIds { get; set; }
    public int CurrentQuestionNumber { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public bool HintAsked { get; set; }
    public bool LocationHintAsked { get; set; }
}
```

**Unit test sample:**

```
 var fakeMemberMock = Fixture.Create<Mock<Members>>();
 fakeMemberMock.SetupSet(members => members.HintAsked = false);
 fakeMemberMock.VerifyGet(members => members.HintAsked, Times.Exactly(1));
```

Since none of my model's properties are virtual, this will result in an error at runtime.

I want to know if there is any reason I should **not** make my EF Core models all virtual for
this purpose.

I am not to sure of any sideffects this may have with interaction with my database or any pros and cons of doing this. I know virtual is generally placed on navigational properties but i do not know wether doing this on normal properties is a good idea or not.

Feel free to mention another method of going about what I am attempting that would be simpler.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the main problem here is that `Member` should encapsulate this `AddToUserScore` method (i.e. the "tell, don't ask" principle). So you just call something like `member.UpdateUserScore()` and check its `UserScore` property before and afterwards. That's just one small aspect of making code testable without changing it for the sole purpose of making a test suite happy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will keep that in mind for future testing, I agree that your suggestion is better for testing than my proposition, didn't like the idea of changing stuff to suite a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me ask, isn't testing the internals of the method too granular? The alternative would be testing the method instead of the model class. The method does a unit of work which is testable.

```
// test case 1
var model1 = new Members();
model1.UserScore = 10;
model1.HintAsked = true;

// run the method AddToUserScore on model

// do the asserts
Assert.Equal(..., model1.UserScore);

// test case 2
var model1 = new Members();
model1.UserScore = 10;
model1.LocationHintAsked = true;
```

Comment: The code I shared was just a snippit of the larger public method, there are a few more assignments similar to that in the public method. Being unable to mock those, I can pretty much verify that the member object is not null and that public method returned true or false. All the granular details that make up the method would be taken out. 
I rely on my tests to not have set values by default since an actual member may have varying values.
Your approach looks like it would be the only alternative though, I may just follow this approach instead. Thanks for the example.